# Determine the hardware and software requirement WPF application

Tags: wpf

I had create a WPF application and i am doing a documentation about it. Inside my documentation, i need to state down the hardware and software requirement for my WPF application. Is that anyway i can check the requirements for the WPF application? Thanks.

About my application:

```
 Target Framework: .NET Framework 4 client profile    
 Output type : Windows Application
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question 100% but I will try anyway to help you.

When developing with WPF, among other things, the graphics hardware is a very important element.

The level of graphics hardware capability and performance for a device that runs a WPF application is defined by [rendering tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx). The MSDN link describes the types of tiers and the minimum graphics hardware.

In short you can get the render tier for the current thread using [RenderCapability.Tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx).

In code

```
int renderingTier = (RenderCapability.Tier >> 16);
```

If you make use of some heavy graphics effects in your WPF application, then it is probably suggested to run it on a system with `RenderCapability.Tier > 0`.